# GIT cli taken from eclipse and used in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, command-line-interface

Hey all I have 2 questions. The first being the most desirable.

1) Can I see the commands that eclipse sends when I use the GIT view? Is there some type of log that outputs what eclipse called?

2) If one above does not work then I have the following as my steps in eclipse that I do to push a modified file(s):

1. Create a branch if no branch is present.
2. Checkout as new local branch dev.
3. Checkout as new local branch devint.
4. Select dev and PULL.
5. Select branch and make modifications to file(s) that are needed.
6. Save changes and then commit with message.
7. Select devint.
8. Merge branch into devint.
9. Commit with message and Commit & Push.
10. Select dev and PULL.
11. Select branch.

I am wanting to do the same as the above but in the **GIT cli**. There are a **LOT** of choices to choose from and I am not sure the java code below is doing 1-11 above.

```
checkout -b bug_" + storyNum //<--Create a new branch.
//*********************************************(do some changes within here)
commit --all -m \"" + comment + "\"" //<--commit branch with message.
//*********************************************
checkout devint //<--check out from branch to devint.
merge -v --no-ff bug_" + storyNum + " -m BUG " + storyNum + " " + whatWasChanged  //<--merge changes in branch into devint.
//*********************************************
checkout dev //<--check out from devint to dev.
pull //<--Check for anything new
checkout bug_" + storyNum //<-return back to the branch.
```

This does not seem to work for half those steps. It commits the branch changes just fine (I think - its not longer in the staged changes state) but leaves everything else untouched.

If someone more knowledgeable at GIT cli commands then please help :o)

Comment: [EGit](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/) does not send commands to the Git command line, but uses [JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/), a Git implementation in Java. You can use JGit in your Java application. What's your goal? A batch/shell script or a Java application? At which step do you get stuck?

Comment: @howlger im planning on making a application. It seems to get messed up after i switch over the devint to merge and everything after that.